# Wrap a function without changing the call sites?

Tags: c++, linker, overriding, hook, pointer-aliasing

Suppose a function `int foo(int x)` is made available in library `libfoo`, which I don't control. I do control a codebase which calls `foo()` many times, in many files.

Now, I would like to insert some logic before actually making a call to `foo()`. Let's say its "if condition holds call foo, otherwise do something else" (and never mind the details). So far - not a problem. I write a `int foo_wrapper(int x)` put my logic in there, and call that one instead.

Now for the hard part: I want to not change the code at the call sites. i.e. I still want there to be `foo()` calls. So:

- No `foo_` almost-same-name functions
- No macro trickery to replace the call
- No pre-compilation source code generation

Essentially I want most of my compilation units to "not look" at libfoo, but at some translation unit I provide with a wrapper `int foo()`; and have the implementation in that translation unit actually call libfoo's `foo()` function. How achievable is this (without twisting myself into knots too hard)?

Additional information about `libfoo`:

- It is a static library; in the case of a dynamic library, one could play with the library search path and have the wrapper be located instead of the original; and then the wrapper might be able to dynamically locate `libfoo` itself, load it, and have the original `foo` symbol available for use when necessary.
- I'm working on Linux, and being cross-platform is not a requirement; of course it's always nice to maintain that.

---

Note: A solution which also works for C code is preferable but not required.

Comment: I would just do the work. I would create an abstract base class (interface) modeling how I would like to use the 3rd party library and implement the wrapper. And then use dependency injection into the code that needs it. Added benefit you can inject a mock of the library for unit testing and if you want to switch libraries too you at least have a decoupling point in your software too. I like design choices to be explicit in my code... but yes that does involve changing the call sites

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I'm not sure what you mean. The constraint is that the code at the call site doesn't change. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Indeed my approach will affect the call site (but only once).

Comment: You can probably re-point the symbols in the object file import table. Would that fit the bill (`nm` and `objcopy` can do renamings, IIRC)? Otherwise, the “canonical” solution on systems with ld.so is to set `LD_PRELOAD` (and similar for macOS).

Comment: You want to change function's call without changing code of neither the function nor the call site? Then that is trivial, you have to change the C++ compiler. If in C too then change C compiler too. Or ... if you don't want to change compiler either then where you want your code to be?

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Let me clarify a bit in the question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Something like that. Can I do this during compilation itself? As a transformation on object files? Only during linking?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: If I were willing to do that, I'd just implement a wrapper function and be done with it.

Comment: @einpoklum At a previous company we performed object file symbol renaming as part of the build process in the Makefile before linking. Unfortunately I don’t remember the nitty-gritty details, otherwise I’d write an answer.

Comment: What is `libfoo`? Is is static/dynamic library? Does this have to work on any platform? Matt Godbolt when showing some features of compiler explorer show how you can inject on Linux alternative version of dynamic library function (do not have link to this talk - I think it was one of cppcon talks). He did it to capture some dangerous function calls to prevent hacks of his site.

Comment: Not sure this is current link (do not have time to watch this again), but take a look on this: https://youtu.be/dOfucXtyEsU?si=ZZCTLdMpSKtEyGZs but quick scanning I think this is proper talk.

Comment: @MarekR: Ah, I see where you're going with this. That's a good idea, but alas I'm using a static library; added this information to the question.

Comment: I think Matt also covers something with static linking too. There might be some clue there for static library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How achievable is this (without twisting myself into knots too hard)?

Trivially achievable given the Linux-only constraint.

If `libfoo` was a shared library, this is *exactly* what library interposers do using `LD_PRELOAD` and similar tricks.

But since `libfoo` is an archive library, all you need to do is rename all your *unresolved* references from `foo` to `foo_wrapper`. You can do that by running `objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_wrapper caller.o new_caller.o`, where `caller.o` is your object file that was originally calling `foo`, and linking your binary using `new_caller.o`.

(Obviously your can do "update in place" with something like `objcopy ... caller.o /tmp/$$.o && mv /tmp/$$.o caller.o`, so you don't have to actually modify your link line.)

You will have to repeat this for every object in your codebase.

P.S. Using a macro to achieve the exact same result is *probably* much simpler -- all you have to do is use `-Dfoo=foo_wrapper` on compilation command line. Not sure whether that counts as "macro trickery" in your book.

Comment: I actually tried proposing the macro solution to my team-mates, but they weren't happy about it. Anyway, `objcopy` seems to be what I need for my approach. Is this impossible on Windows for some reason, or are you just not familiar with the Windows equivalents?

Comment: @einpoklum The `objcopy` approach is likely to work on Windows as well (and indeed on any platform supported by `binutils`).